# Accessing CD/DVD drive for backup from Adobe AIR application

Tags: air, adobe, dvd-burning, cd-burning

Is it possible to burn a CD/DVD from an Adobe AIR app?
How?
I want my application to take some backup on the CD/DVD.
Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

While there may be an external library somewhere that can do this, AIR cannot burn CDs or DVDs out of the box.  The best it can do is read, write and copy files on the local file system.

If you want to back up data, you can write your data elsewhere on the file system.